# Regular expression in text editor

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-editor, textpad

I have a requirement to replace all the below numbers to TAB in text Editors like notepad++. I tried the below regular expression but it still needs some manually work. Can anyone help to achieve this in single regular expression.

I used the below one and  manually removed the [1-9]. factor to get all the lines.

\<3.1.[1-9].[1-9].[1-9].

```html
3.1. Cre
3.1.1. Im
3.1.1.1. O
3.1.1.2. Ce
3.1.1.3. Part
3.1.2. ED
3.1.2.1. Ow
3.1.2.2. ED
3.1.3. OF
3.1.3.1. O
3.1.3.2. O
3.1.3.3. O
3.1.3.4. O
3.1.4. Sc
3.1.5. In
3.1.6. Vi
3.1.7. Bu
3.1.8. Ho
3.1.8.1. Ou
3.1.8.2. In
3.1.9. Pa
3.1.9.1. Re
3.1.9.2. Re
3.1.9.3. Pr
3.1.9.3.1. Ou
3.1.9.3.2. Sp
3.1.9.3.3. In
3.1.9.3.4. In
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for

`^3[.1-9]+\s`

and replace with

`\t`

It works in NotePad++ on my computer.

**UPDATE**:
A more generic regex in NotePad++ for bullet point removal:

Search: `^[.0-9]+\s([A-Z])`

Replace with `\t\1`

Comment: It will not replace `3.1.10`.

Comment: 3.1.10 is not there present in input, its letter "O" not zero

Comment: Well, I adjusted the regex for the input, but in case you need something more generic, surely `^[.0-9]+\s([A-Z])` to replace with `\t\1` will be better,

Answer (score 1):

```
^3(?:\.\d+)*\.\s*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/wU7sQ0/39

Comment: I tried it in notepad++ it its not able to find the regex, may be what you mentioned is for some other programming language